# Using TypeScript With SharePoint 2013

Tags: sharepoint, typescript1.6

I am following this article step by step [http://www.itunity.com/article/typescript-sharepoint-2013-app-1290][1]

I cannot get my "app.ts" file to compile to the "app.js" file.  I am logged on as admin and have enabled "Automatically compile TypeScript" files which are not part of a project in Visual Studio 2013.

When I build and or deploy,  I just cannot get an "app.js" file to generate.

Answer (score 0):

Logging on as "Admin" with Visual Studio 2013 was causing this issue.